# Select records limited to those with specific value of a second table

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

I have a user table.  I have another table called diagnoses with user id, and with a field called PHgroup that has a bunch of values (1 through 5) for each users.  I want to ONLY select patients who have a value of "1" in the PHgroup and exclude any patient who has any other value other than 1.  When I run this query I get all the records of users with a value of 1 even if they have another PHgroup entry with a value of, say 4.

```
$query= "SELECT *, users.id as usersid, diagnoses.PHgroup, 
diagnoses.date_dx FROM users
inner join diagnoses on diagnoses.user_id = users.id
where diagnoses.PHgroup = '1' and NOT (diagnoses.PHgroup ='2' and 
diagnoses.PHgroup ='3'and diagnoses.PHgroup ='4')";
```

How do I select only users with a value of 1 in PHgroup table and not patients who have other values (even if they also have group 1 as well)

To clarify: if a user has an entry with a value of 1 and anotehr entry with a value of 4, I do not want to select that user.
Only users who have a value of 1 and no other entry with a value other than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You want to query ids from the diagnosis table where patients are not in PHgroup 2-5.

You can do this with CTEs (not sure what mysql version you're running) or with nested queries.

Use this as your where clause to only get results where PHgroup = 1:

```
where users.id in (select user_id from diagnoses where user_id not in (select user_id 
from diagnoses where PHgroup in (2,3,4,5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query= "SELECT users.id as usersid FROM users
inner join diagnoses on diagnoses.user_id = users.id
group by users.id having max(diagnoses.PHgroup) = 1;
```

It's not very extensible, but does solve the case where you want diagnosis 1 and no others (given that the numbers are 1-5 and 1 is the lowest).  Of course, you could use it to find, for example, 4 and no others by checking the min and max:

```
$query= "SELECT users.id as usersid FROM users
inner join diagnoses on diagnoses.user_id = users.id
group by users.id having max(diagnoses.PHgroup) = 4
and min(diagnoses.PHgroup) = 4;
```